# Custom react script in package.json is not recognised

Tags: javascript, reactjs, package.json

I added a custom command to run in my react scripts in my package.json file so that I can run an api server from there

```
{
  "name": "appfrontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "start-api": "cd .. && cd appbackend && venv/bin/flask run", # This is the command I added
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

But npm is not recognising this command. What seems to be the issue? Should I not be able to run my new script with

`npm start-api`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to use `npm run start-api`

npm only has a few specific commands it recognizes by default. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-documentation/cli. Anything else you add to your package, you have to use `npm run` in order to get npm to recognize it.